# extraction new generated vectors in module with replaced parts

Tags: list-manipulation, vector, code-review, vector-calculus

We have four vectors:

```
Subscript[B, 1] = {{20}, {10}, {5}, {1}};
Subscript[B, 2] = {{1},{5},{10},{20}};
Subscript[B, 3] = {{1}, {10}, {5}, {20}};
Subscript[B, 4] = {{20},{1}, {5}, {10}};
```

We wrote a short code to find every vector which has followed numbers `10 and 20`. After finding, replacing them and all component and other vectors remain unchanged. the wrong commands happen because: (in `ReplacePart` we could not able to give a suitable all `a` components, we just wrote `ReplacePart[a]`! also we could not able to see some changed vectors but with a new name not with name of Bi's because each defined variable in module, is temporary for example the name 'new' for new vectors):
As a matter of fact we want to see:

```
 desire results
 Subscript[new, 1] = {{10}, {20}, {5}, {1}};
 Subscript[new, 2] = {{1}, {5}, {20}, {10}};


 the code:
Do[
   Do[
   If[(Subscript[B, i][[j]] == 20 \[And]Subscript[B, i][[j + 1]] == 10)     \[Or] 
      (Subscript[B, i][[j]] == 10 \[And] Subscript[B, i][[j + 1]] == 20),

 Module[ {a = Subscript[B, i]}, 
 ReplacePart[{a}, {j -> a[[j + 1]], j + 1 -> a[[j]]}]]]
 ,{j, 1, 3}]
 ,{i, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want, but are you trying to change the vector  assigned to `Subscript[B,i]`? Because the variable `a` inside the `Module` is a variable internal to the `Module`, and so changing its value will not change the value of `Subscript[B,i]`. If so, getting rid of the Module might help. I also recommend not using `Subscript`s and using `b[i]` or something like that instead. In addition, `ReplacePart` does not have the side effect of changing the value of `a`.

Comment: No the desire result wrote with Subscript[new, 1] = {{10}, {20}, {5}, {1}};
 Subscript[new, 2] = {{1}, {5}, {20}, {10}};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimally-changed working version of what you want, I think:

```
Do[
  Do[
    If[
      (Subscript[B, i][[j]] == {20} && Subscript[B, i][[j + 1]] == {10}) || (Subscript[B, i][[j]] == {10} && Subscript[B, i][[j + 1]] == {20})
      , Subscript[new, i] = Module[
          {a = Subscript[B, i]}
          , ReplacePart[a, {j -> a[[j + 1]], j + 1 -> a[[j]]}]]]
    , {j, 1, 3}
  , {i, 1, 4}]
```

First, `Subscript[B, 1][[1]]` has the value `{20}` rather than `20`, so the conditionals in your `If` statement weren't matching. Once this is corrected, `Module` does output the correct vectors. I have the output of the `Module` now assigned to `Subscript[new, i]`, as you wanted.

Now, I would make a few preliminary changes to simplify the code. First, the two `Do` loops can be made into one. Second, we can check for the sequences `{10},{20}` and `{20},{10}` directly by using spans of `Part`. Finally, we should not use `Subscript`s, as they act strange in Mathematica. These changes result in

```
b[1] = {{20}, {10}, {5}, {1}};
b[2] = {{1},{5},{10},{20}};
b[3] = {{1}, {10}, {5}, {20}};
b[4] = {{20},{1}, {5}, {10}};

Do[
  If[b[i][[j ;; j + 1]] == {{20}, {10}} || b[i][[j ;; j + 1]] == {{10}, {20}}
    , new[i] = Module[{a = b[i]}
        , ReplacePart[a, {j -> a[[j + 1]], j + 1 -> a[[j]]}]
        ]
    ]
  , {j, 1, 3}, {i, 1, 4}]
```

**Update**

Now, if we'd like to start playing around with a little bit more of Mathematica's clever functionality, we could come up with a pattern matching version that also uses `Scan` instead of `Do`. This version is sort of kluge-y, and it also has the side-effect of assigning `new[3]` and `new[4]` to `b[3]` and `b[4]`, but we can fix that later.

```
Scan[(
    new[#] = b[#] /. {{x___, {20}, {10}, z___} :> {x, {10}, {20}, z}, {x___, {10}, {20}, z___} :> {x, {20}, {10}, z}}
  ) &, Range[4]]
```

This version takes the function defined in the first argument of `Scan` and applies it to every element of the second argument. So it takes the values `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` (the elements of `Range[4]`) and consecutively puts them in the `Slot` (`#`), at which time the right-hand side of the `=` is evaluated. In this right hand side, we find patterns that match `{anything, {20},{10},anything}` or `{anything, {10},{20},anything}` and replace them with the switched version. This is then assigned to `new[i]`, which is why there is the side effect of assigning all of the `new[i]`s.

Comment: Update version is more interesting, thanks a bunch for complete explanation. Your explanation, removed some other ambiguous cases.

Comment: @mr Thanks! If I have the time, I might continue to come up with more versions that are both more concise and more general, and also use different Mathematica idioms. Stay tuned?

Comment: this is enough, Associated comment were so fruitful.

Comment: @mr.0093 Glad I could help!